# Why TestBed beforeeach uses waitForAsync instead of just async/await compileComponents?

Tags: angular, testing, async-await

**EDIT : I opened an issue at Angular and they updated the docs** : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39740

In Angular tests the usual thing is to do this for the `beforeEach` method

```typescript
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed
          .configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [BannerComponent],
          })
          .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    }));
```

What's the difference with doing the following ?

```typescript
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed
          .configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [BannerComponent],
          })
          .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    });
```

I tried to find an explanation in the docs but couldn't figure it out.

https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync#description
https://v10.angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#the-async-beforeeach

Answer (score 17):

### About the two methods

We have various ways we can define async operations in testing angular operation

- using `waitForAsync()`

> [**waitForAsync**](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync)
>
> Wraps a test function in an asynchronous test zone. The test will automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone are done. Can be used to wrap an inject call.
> From the doc

It is also important to note that this method is a renaming of the initial method `async`.

> <strike>**[async](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/async)**</strike>
>
> **Deprecated**: use `waitForAsync()`, (expected removal in v12)
>
> **async() helper renamed**
>
> The testing helper function `async` has been deprecated and renamed `waitForAsync`.
>
> The reason behind this renaming is that it can be confusing to have a function named `async()` when we now have a JavaScript keyword named `async` (that keyword did not exist when the Angular function was created), which is slightly similar (you can `await` asynchronous calls), but different (`async()` waits for all asynchronous calls, where `async` only waits for the calls marked with await).
>
> Credit to `Cédric Exbrayat` [See this article](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2020/09/03/what-is-new-angular-10.1/#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20behind%20this%20renaming,async()%20waits%20for%20all)

`WaitForAsync` function executes the code inside its body in a special async test zone. This keeps track of all the promises that are created in the body. The function also tracks any promises created by nested function for example if we call an asynchronous function in in the ngOnInit function, this would be tracked.

- Using `Async/ Await`

Basically this uses the normal Javascript `async\ await`. We declare a function as async and await for a promise to resolve

### What is difference between the two approaches?

Let consider a test with 5 methods `asyncMethod1`,`nonAsyncMethod1`, `asyncMethod2`, `asyncMethod3`, `nonAsyncMethod2`.

Using `async / await`. we will need to do below

```typescript
beforeEach(async () => {
   await asyncMethod1();
   nonAsyncMethod1(); 
   await asyncMethod2();
   await asyncMethod3();
   nonAsyncMethod2()
   await TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [BannerComponent],
      })
      .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
});
```

using `waitForAsync` the above would be

```typescript
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
   asyncMethod1();
   nonAsyncMethod1(); 
   asyncMethod2();
   asyncMethod3();
   nonAsyncMethod2()
   TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [BannerComponent],
      })
      .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
}));
```

So generally when using `async /await`, we would need to track all our asynchronous operations while using `waitForAsync` this would be tracked by the function and promise resolved once all promises in the body of the function have been resolved

Comment: So there is no difference between my two snippets.

Comment: The two snippets will function exactly the same, though I would recommend using `waitForAsync`.

Comment: OK well this is weird because Angular 11 CLI generates a test file using async/await and not waitForAsync

Comment: here I am using async as a JS operation, this is not the refactored async function from Angular

Comment: @YohanDahmani the v12 docs will have this fixed and use the async: https://next.angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios

Comment: @Juri Yes this is because I opened an issue on Angular GitHub, they fixed it last week https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39740

Comment: Just here to say Angular 12 generated spec files for a component are still using `async`/`await` by default instead of `waitForAsync`

Comment: Angular generates using `async`/`await`, because TestBed.compileComponents doesn't need to be called in a test zone. Also, Angular doesn't require that `waitForAsync` be used. It's just an option.